# Send custom push notification to IOS?

Tags: php, ios, iphone, push-notification, notifications

I have a server with some scheduled tasks which frequently require manual intervention (where I need to say skip this, for example). I want to be able to send a warning to my iPhone in such a situation.

I don't want to signup for Apple developer program or create a dedicated app to push notifications for this because I am the only one who will use this. 
In Android, it is fine. I could send a notification to Chrome browser but I dont want to change my mobile.

Currently, my server sends an sms to my mobile (php script) but it is costly. (email is not an option because I need it quickly wit 1 minute accuracy.

I looked at other solutions for example, if I can send a message to my whatsapp or facebook messenger. But apparently, they dont have an API.  I also searched if there is any IOS chat app which allows me to send a message to myself programmatically. But there is not.

Are there any other option for IOS to allow notifying myself?

Comment: how about pushover? https://pushover.net/. seems like able to achieve what you need. (Do note that it requires a one-time-purchase license once free trials is over)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Signup for free account at [HipChat Basic](https://www.hipchat.com/) by [Atlassian](https://www.atlassian.com/)
2. Create a room (It is where all message will be sent and viewed ) during the signup process. As an Admin, You can make that room as "Private" or "Public" in Permissions tab.
3. As an Admin, Go to *"Rooms" -> "Your room" -> "Summary"* tab and write down **API ID** (i.e. ROOM_ID).
4. In *"Rooms" -> "Your room" -> "Tokens"*, Generate a **Room Notification Token** ( i.e. AUTH_TOKEN ) for your room  and write it down.
5. Assuming you are on *nix Server with cURL installed. Use this bash script from [HipChat API v2 - Send a message to a room using cURL](https://gist.github.com/danriti/7345074) to send a notification to your Room created in above step.

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
>
> # Set the ROOM_ID & AUTH_TOKEN variables below.
> # Further instructions at https://www.hipchat.com/docs/apiv2/auth
>
> ROOM_ID=XXX
> AUTH_TOKEN=XXX
> MESSAGE="@username:Hello world!"
>
> curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
>      -X POST \
>      -d "{\"color\": \"purple\", \"message_format\": \"text\", \"message\": \"$MESSAGE\" }" \
>      https://api.hipchat.com/v2/room/$ROOM_ID/notification?auth_token=$AUTH_TOKEN
> ```

6. Modify **ROOM_ID** and **AUTH_TOKEN** in the script using values generated in above steps
7. Install IOS/Android App on your Phone and logged in.
8. Run the bash script to send a test message to your room from your Server and check it out on your mobile device.
9. To set notification preferences like someone mentions you (enabled by default) or there is a new message etc. on each app / platform on which you are using HipChat, Go to your "Account Settings" -> "Notifications" section and make appropriate changes ( App notification, SMS notification etc )
10. If sender and receiver are using the same account, then mention your username using "@username" in the message to get notify.

Comment: Thanks. Tested with a simple php script. It works for both Android and IOS as they have native app. 
For IOS notifications, you need to mention the username using @, otherwise it won't notify. (Their docs say it should, but it didnt.). So, in the message I added @my_username. It is great. thanks.

Comment: Because it @username notification is enabled by default in "Account Settings". For other notification preferences, Please check "Notifications" in your "Account Settings".

Comment: Correct. If sender and receiver are using the same account then to get notify, you need to mention your username in the message.

Comment: No,the strange thing is it works fine for Android without @ and you still receive a notification (different accounts). In iPhone, it wont alert you if your name is not mentioned, I am not sure why. All options are enabled in Settings.

Comment: HipChat has been discontinued. Anybody interested can use Telegram for self-notifications

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you need to give [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com) a look, you can accomplish all of things mentioned above, and it may actually streamline your entire project. Hope this helps!

Comment: But I dont have to build and maintain an app. Also, an IOS app requires Apple certificate.

Comment: Chances are everything is going to need the certificate. Unless your apple device is jailbroken it needs the key because without it apple devices would be vulnerable to spam from just about everywhere.

Comment: I am also fine if there is an existing IOS app which I can install on my phone and use its API to notify myself.